# How To Select data from multiple tables with grouping for duplicates

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have Two Tables, one with Employees Details and another with vacations taken by them in different years.[Please check this image for the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2HAl.png)

Here as you'll find out in the vacation table, for the same employee with same employeeId and in sam year different vacation days are mentioned. Like John Smith in 2011 have two entries one with 10 vacation and one with 3 vacation. I want my query to return a single row with vacations mentioned as 13.

I tried the following query but no luck

```sql
SELECT Employee_Details.EmployeeId, Employee_Details.EmployeeName, Employees_Vacation.Year, Employees_Vacation.Vacation, Employee_Details.Department
FROM Employees_Vacation INNER JOIN Employee_Details ON Employees_Vacation.EmployeeId=Employee_Details.EmployeeId group by Employee_Details.EmployeeId ORDER BY Employee_Details.EmployeeName, Employees_Vacation.Year ;
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and improve your question.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here. Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are really using.

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Can you share the expected result for this sample data?

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you right, i think this may help you

```
select sum(vacation) as sum, ev.year, ed.EmployeeName from employee_Details as ed inner join employee_Vacation as ev
on ed.employeeID = ev.employeeID 
group by ev.year, ed.EmployeeName
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot here will depend on the sql engine you are using, however there are some things that will apply regardless of the engine to consider:

1. Your current GROUP BY clause is grouping only by employeeId - from the question text it *seems* like you are instead looking for results grouped by employee AND vacation year
2. Your projection (SELECT statement) currently isn't actually aggregating anything - it's just projecting a bunch of fields. On some db engines, this actually isn't even allowed (SQL Server for example will only allow grouped or aggregated columns in the projection). Again, from the question text it *seems* like you are looking for the SUM of vacation days per employee and year.

Taking these into account and assuming the assumptions made are accurate, something like the following should work in most/all modern RDBMS's:

```
SELECT Employee_Details.EmployeeId,
       Employee_Details.EmployeeName,
       Employees_Vacation.Year,
       SUM(Employees_Vacation.Vacation) AS TotalVacationDays,
       Employee_Details.Department
FROM Employees_Vacation
INNER JOIN Employee_Details
ON Employees_Vacation.EmployeeId = Employee_Details.EmployeeId
GROUP BY
    Employee_Details.EmployeeId, Employee_Details.EmployeeName,
    Employees_Vacation.Year, Employee_Details.Department
ORDER BY
    Employee_Details.EmployeeName,
    Employee_Details.EmployeeId,
    Employees_Vacation.Year;
```

You may be able to get away with fewer grouping clauses in some engines (MySql for example). Additionally I added an EmployeeId to the order by clause to ensure records for the same employee remain together in the results (for employees with the same names for example).